# How to reduce logging on my live site?

Tags: magento2, logging, production

In Magento 2, can I reduce the logging for my production site?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please add more details for your question.

Comment: On my production site I can see there are a lot of debug messages in my /var/log/system.log. As Magento uses monolog I was hoping the verbosity could be dialled down a bit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes we hit the same issue!
We have developed a module that can be installed by running:
`composer require zero1/module-custom-logging`
The docs can be seen [here](https://github.com/zero1limited/magento2-CustomLogging).

This allows you to change the logging level on a per environment basis. We use "production" in production :p and "non_production" in dev environments. e.g local machine / Mdoq / shared staging server. There is no reason why you couldn't add others.

The changes you make in `app/etc/env.php` are meant to be environment specific. In here you can configure the logging 'stack' you want to use. This value will be out of source control. The 'stack' is purely a nice name to a set of logging configuration defined in `app/etc/config.php`
In `app/etc/config.php` you can configure as many different stacks as you want e.g 'production', 'staging', 'local'. Each of these stacks is stored in source control allowing the stacks to be used by anyone on your code base.

In addition to be able to change the 'stack' with a single environment value, we can also add additional things to all loggers, so that all messages get this info. The default example adds four 'processors' that add extra info.

```php
'common_processors' => [
    \Monolog\Processor\GitProcessor::class,
    \Monolog\Processor\IntrospectionProcessor::class,
    \Monolog\Processor\WebProcessor::class,
    \Zero1\CustomLogging\Logger\Processor\HardwareInstance::class,
]
```

These will be added to all handlers:

```php
'handlers' => [
    'nonProductionDefaultLogger' => [],
    'nonProductionDebugLogger' => [],
 ]
```

These link to the loggers that are defined in `etc/di.xml`

How this is different from Magento core:
 - In magento core, you would have to make changes in source controlled files to change the logging verbosity. (Not ideal as production should have the same source files as staging, yet they should have different logging verbosity / settings)
- In magento core there is no way to configure different stacks of loggers.

Hope this helps

Comment: Looks interesting. Can you explain a bit more on how this extension works? And what the different settings mean.